# How to update images or save new images in web in Android

Tags: android, database

I am getting data from server, it works fine.Image successfully getting display with application. But, Now I want to take new photo from camera or from SD card and update that images which is getting from web.Here , Image must be save on server and replace old web images to new photo that is take from camera or SD card.

I did not have much more idea behind this trick, could you please give me basic idea.How to update current images to new images.

Comment: you have used database on server side?? if yes then upload image to server and update that image name in table..

Comment: Yes I have used database on server side. Please if you have any idea or little code how to do this, please forward your message again.

Comment: you have created web services for getdata from server?? same as you have to create web service fro upload file. after uploading you have to execute update query on server side that 'll be update table in your database.

Comment: here is code how upload image on server http://development-in-android.blogspot.in/2012/09/upload-image-from-android-to-server.html